# Javascript: Reload page after window.location

Tags: javascript, window, load, reload

I have the following function called by a button that redirects to an specific page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function procesar(xform){window.location.href = "vtas3.php?id=<?php echo ''.$id.'';?>&fn=<?php echo ''.$fn.'';?>";}</script>
```

But when the page loads does not refresh data content in the database and I have to reload the page in order to see the updated information.

I've tried to refresh automatically using: `parent.window.location.reload(true);` 
but it reloads continously.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be a victim of browser caching. Try adding a random variable to the URL, e.g. (note the new "t" parameter):

```
window.location.href = "vtas3.php?t=<?=rand()?>&id=<?php echo ''.$id.'';?>&fn=<?php echo ''.$fn.'';?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function procesar(xform){
        window.location.href = "vtas3.php?id=<?php echo ''.$id.'';?>&fn=<?php echo ''.$fn.'';?>&" + (new Date()).getTime();
    }
 </script>
```

**What does this code do?**

It add the current time as ticks to the end of URL. Doing this, the browser you catch it as a new request without caching.

This is used on AJAX requests also to solve the same problem.

Comment: This works sometimes. Not always.
Thanks for your help!